# How to pprint to file parameters of an Instance from an AbstractModel in Pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

I´m trying to inspect an Instance of an AbstractModel on Pyomo for checking if parameters reading was OK.

For doing so, I´d like to print the parameters values considered in the instance into a txt file.

for doing so, I´ve tried:

```
for element in instance.component_objects(Param,descend_into=True):
   element.pprint(filename=some_filename)
```

But what I get is that filename is not a valid argument for pprint. Any hints on what could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pprint` expects an output stream to write to. Try:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    element.pprint(output_file)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!